# ToolTip issue skipping Rows in Datagrid

Tags: c#, datagrid, datatable, tooltip, c#-2.0

```
private void datagridSignal_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) 
{         this.toolTip.Hide(datagridSignal);         
this.toolTip.RemoveAll();         
DataTable dt = GetSignalTable();         
DataView dv = new DataView(dt);         
Point prop = new Point(e.X, e.Y);         
System.Windows.Forms.DataGrid.HitTestInfo myHitTest;                 
myHitTest = datagridSignal.HitTest(prop.X, prop.Y);         
this.toolTip.SetToolTip(datagridSignal, " ID = '" + (int)dv[myHitTest.Row][0] + "'  '" + myHitTest.Row + "'"); 
}
```

this is my code thus far, unfortunately it isn't providing accurate results.. for some reason it will randomly mix up the order of ID's even though the correct index is being displayed.

***using datagrid , not datagridview

***visual C# 2.0 in Visualstudio2005 environment

EDIT:

```
private void dataGridSignal_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
  this.toolTip.Hide(dataGridSignal); 
  this.toolTip.RemoveAll(); 
  System.Windows.Forms.DataGrid.HitTestInfo myHitTest;  
  myHitTest = dataGridSignal.HitTest(e.X, e.Y);
  this.toolTip.SetToolTip(dataGridSignal, " ID = " + ((int)this.GetTable().Rows[myHitTest.Row][0]).ToString() + " "+ myHitTest.Row.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Can't you just use `datagridSignal` instead of dt and dv?  Along with the prop variable, they all seem unnecessary.

Comment: yeah, that would clean the code up, but I figured I'd use the variables just to make it as clear as possible for the question. It doesnt help solve my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't duplicate it.  This worked for me:

```
void dg_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
  this.toolTip1.Hide(dg);
  this.toolTip1.RemoveAll();

  System.Windows.Forms.DataGrid.HitTestInfo myHitTest = dg.HitTest(e.X, e.Y);

  if (myHitTest.Row > -1) {
    this.toolTip1.SetToolTip(dg, "Over " + dt.Rows[myHitTest.Row][0].ToString());
    this.Text = "Over " + dt.Rows[myHitTest.Row][0].ToString();
  }
}
```

I can only guess that the DataSource that the DataGrid is using is different than the one coming from `GetSignalTable`.  In my example, `dt` is the DataTable that my DataGrid dg is using.

Comment: checked, this makes no difference sadly

Comment: @DarthSheldon Updated answer.  I can only guess that your `GetSignalTable` is different than the one the grid is actually using.

Comment: probably not, as several other functions use my gettable function and they seem just fine

Comment: @DarthSheldon Instead of `GetSignalTable`, why not try casting it: `DataTable dt = (DataTable)dataGridSignal.DataSource;`

Comment: this actually made the tooltip nolonger function

Comment: ok, so you are a wise wise individual. by using
     
    
    DataView dv = (DataView)dataGridSignal.DataSource;
now it works like a top. KUDOS!